# Can derived tables be correlated subqueries in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

It has always been my understanding that a **subquery** is just a query that is nested inside of another query.

And that a **correlated subquery** is a subquery that uses columns from the outer query.

The documentation here seems to support that idea, I think.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html

---

Now, the part that confuses me.

I'm reading this,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Specifically,

> A derived table cannot be a correlated subquery.

And,

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.14, a derived table cannot contain outer references. This is a MySQL restriction that is lifted in MySQL 8.0.14, not a restriction of the SQL standard. For example, the derived table dt in the following query contains a reference `t1.b` to the table `t1` in the outer query:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM t1
> WHERE t1.d > (SELECT AVG(dt.a)
>                 FROM (SELECT SUM(t2.a) AS a
>                       FROM t2
>                       WHERE t2.b = t1.b GROUP BY t2.c) dt
>               WHERE dt.a > 10);
> ```

---

It says that a derived table cannot be a correlated subquery. So, it cannot use columns from the outer query.

Then, it says that the restriction is lifted and it can use columns from the outer query.

Am I misunderstanding/misreading something here?

---

[Edit]

I gave this a little more thought and I *think* I get what it's saying. (not too sure).

So, there are two kinds of derived-table-as-correlated-subqueries, I think.

---

One references tables from the **same** `FROM/JOIN` clause.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sameFromClauseTable
JOIN
    --This derived table references `sameFromClauseTable.sameFromClauseColumn`
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            innerTable
        WHERE
            --This expression references `sameFromClauseTable.sameFromClauseColumn`
            sameFromClauseTable.sameFromClauseColumn > innerTable.innerColumn
    ) AS derivedTable
```

- This is not allowed in MySQL 5.7
- This is not allowed in MySQL 8.0
- This can work with `LATERAL` in MySQL 8.0

---

The other references tables from the **parent** `FROM/JOIN` clause.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    parentQueryTable
WHERE
    --This is a subquery
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            --This derived table references `parentQueryTable.parentQueryColumn`
            (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    innerTable
                WHERE
                    --This expression references `parentQueryTable.parentQueryColumn`
                    parentQueryTable.parentQueryColumn > innerTable.innerColumn
            ) AS derivedTable
    )
```

- This is not allowed in MySQL 5.7
- This is allowed in MySQL 8.0

---

I haven't actually run any of these queries so I might have it completely wrong. I hope someone can check if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: The restriction is lifted with a new keyword `LATERAL` being introduced. Check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html

But that does not mean that Derived tables are now correlated subqueries. Both are different in behaviour

Comment: Here is a blog my MySQL team explaining the feature with some examples: https://mysqlserverteam.com/support-for-lateral-derived-tables-added-to-mysql-8-0-14/

and one more: https://mysqlserverteam.com/supporting-all-kinds-of-outer-references-in-derived-tables-lateral-or-not/